# explain how does the code of this c# method workes.and what each part is doing

Tags: c#, methods

this is a method in c# that is used in the program to  makes a 10-digit number. my question is that how does this work exactly? what is the code doing?

```
long LongRandom(long min,long max,Random rand)
        {
            long result = rand.Next((Int32)(min >> 32), (Int32)(max >> 32));
            result = (result << 32);
            result = result | (long)rand.Next((Int32)min, (Int32)max);
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Where spüecifically do you have difficulties? Do you you know what an `int` is? What casting means? Or are you stuck on the `<<`? So what are you asking about?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO.. please read [tour] [ask] and [mcve] .. Im sure you've googled a bunch of the bits of that code, what specifically are you struggling with?

Comment: But even without completely understanding those lines - which I have to admit I do neither - it´s ptretty clear to me what the method should do: generate a random number between min and max.

Comment: It gets a random value for the 32 left bits, then a random value for the 32 right bits, and add those two values to get a random `long` (`Int64`) value. However, note that this will **not** get a random value between `min` and `max` as you could expect

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense.  Do not get binary and decimal confused.  Shift by 32 places is binary places not decimal places.  So the code is taking a long signed (should be unsigned) which is 63 bits and removing 32 bits so you have 31 bits.  Which is a number < 2147483648 which is not all 10 digit numbers.  I'm not sure why you are taking a random number and OR'ing with a random number.  Taking a random number and random again doesn't get you any thing more random.  My teacher use to ask if you have a random deck of cards and shuffled again do you get something more or less random.

Comment: @jdweng I think saying that this code doesn't make any sense is a bit harsh. It does indeed have flaws, but it **does** make sense, and it **tries** to solve a well defined problem: "*how do you generate a random big number when you have a tool to generate a random small number?*"

Answer (score 0):

Just consider the following analogy with *decimals* (for simplicity, as we're not computers):

Let's say we have a random generator that can go from 0 to 999, and you want to generate a random number between two numbers in a range `[0, 999.999]`.

What this code does is take anything above 999 in your `min` and `max`, and generate a random number for thousands, then take anything below 1.000 in your `min` and `max` and generate a random number for units below a thousand, then add those values.

However, if you wanted to get a random number between say `20` and `1.080` using this method, you will never be able to get anything in the range `[81, 1019]` for example.

Also note that there's a problem with signed/unsigned values in your code (as stated by jdweng)